# Huxtable package for R: How to set font_size() for caption() and footnote() for huxtables?

Tags: r

Adjusting the font size for the cells in a huxtable is easily possible with the set_font_size() command. However, the font sizes of caption and footnote are not adjusted accordingly as follows from this MWE:

```
HUX_table <- matrix("x", 6, 2)
HUX_table <- as_hux(HUX_table)        %>%
  huxtable::add_colnames()            %>%
  set_all_borders(1)                  %>%
  set_rowspan(c(2, 5), 1, 3)          %>%
  set_font_size(4)                    %>%
  set_caption("Sample Caption")       %>% 
  add_footnote("Sample Footnote")
```

I tried both set_caption_size() and set_caption_font_size() but with little success. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not surprising that those commands don’t work, because they don’t exist. You have to add the raw commands in the `caption`, like this for HTML:

```
caption(hux) <- "<span style='font-size: 8pt'>My caption</span>"
```

And something analogous for TeX.

The footnote issue is subtler. It's natural to assume that `set_font_size(HUX_table, 4)` will set the font size for not only present, but also cells rows. Natural, and maybe that is what should happen, but it doesn't. So put the `font_size` command at the end of your chain, and it will affect the footnote.

```
HUX_table <- as_hux(HUX_table)        %>%
      huxtable::add_colnames()            %>%
      set_all_borders(1)                  %>%
      set_rowspan(c(2, 5), 1, 3)          %>%
      set_caption("<span style='font-size: 8pt'>Sample Caption</span>")       %>% 
      add_footnote("Sample Footnote")     %>% 
      set_font_size(4)
```